# Laravel Eloquent how to limit access to logged in user only

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a small app where users create things that are assigned to them.

There are multiple users but all the things are in the same table.
I show the things belonging to a user by retrieving all the things with that user's id but nothing would prevent a user to see another user's things by manually typing the thing's ID in the URL.

Also when a user wants to create a new thing, I have a validation rule set to unique but obviously if someone else has a thing with the same name, that's not going to work.

Is there a way in my Eloquent Model to specify that all interactions should only be allowed for things belonging to the logged in user?

This would mean that when a user tries to go to /thing/edit and that he doesn't own that thing he would get an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to check that a "thing" belongs to a user in the controller for the  "thing".

For example, in the controller, you could do this:

```
// Assumes that the controller receives $thing_id from the route.
$thing = Things::find($thing_id); // Or how ever you retrieve the requested thing.

// Assumes that you have a 'user_id' column in your "things" table.
if( $thing->user_id == Auth::user()->id ) {
    //Thing belongs to the user, display thing.
} else {
    // Thing does not belong to the current user, display error.
}
```

The same could also be accomplished using relational tables.

```
// Get the thing based on current user, and a thing id 
// from somewhere, possibly passed through route.
// This assumes that the controller receives $thing_id from the route.
$thing = Users::find(Auth::user()->id)->things()->where('id', '=', $thing_id)->first();

if( $thing ) {
    // Display Thing
} else {
    // Display access denied error.
}
```

The 3rd Option:

```
// Same as the second option, but with firstOrFail().
$thing = Users::find(Auth::user()->id)->things()->where('id', '=', $thing_id)->firstOrFail();

// No if statement is needed, as the app will throw a 404 error 
// (or exception if errors    are on)
```

Correct me if I am wrong, I am still a novice with laravel myself. But I believe this is what you are looking to do. I can't help all that much more without seeing the code for your "thing", the "thing" route, or the "thing" controller or how your "thing" model is setup using eloquent (if you use eloquent).

Comment: Yes I can see what you are doing, but I was wondering if there was no way to define in the actual model that you are limiting the results to only "things" having the same user_id as the logged in user. That would prevent me from doing all these checks because there is list, create, edit, update, delete and I have a number of different "things". So really I am asking if this can be set in the Model for Thing...

Comment: Also I believe that having so much code in your controllers is not very good design practice, hence me asking about the possibility in having that restriction set in Models

Comment: If you want to keep it more simple and avoid the if statement, then you can use my 2nd method, and replace `first();` with `firstOrFail();`. This will throw an exception if the "thing" doesn't belong to the user, and you will not need the if statement. I agree that controllers should be kept simple, but I disagree that this thing should be done in a model. I personally think models are how you get your data, not how you act on the data. That the controllers job! Up to you though! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Joe thank you for that I appreciate. This was my option if I couldn't find a way to apply a more general fix, but it looks I might have to go down that road. My controllers are already a mess...

Comment: how about the "unique" issue through the validator though? Will I have to write a custom validation rule?

Comment: This should fix that issue, as instead of looking by name first, it is looking by user id first. The process above goes like so: Get user > get Users things > get thing by `$thing`; So if a user has a thing with the same name, the url would work, but display their thing instead of the other users. It would only cause an issue if the same user has 2 things with the same name. For that, I would think prefixing any things with a duplicate name with `_2` at the end when inputting into the database should work.

Comment: Option 3 is perfect, should have thought about it!

Comment: The "unique" keyword for the validator will just check if there is a "thing" with the same name in the DB, it doesn;t care what user i slogged in, so that bit is not working the way I want. I think I might have to create a custom validation rule for that one as in unique where user id is id

Comment: Actually that bit is in the doc, sorry: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Glad to hear that helped. Ya, the laravel documentation is awesome, you can usually find most answers there!

Comment: I've been struggling to conceptualise this too and do things neatly. In the end I created a Scope within my model called "mine". So now I do `$thing = Thing::mine()->get();`. The scope is simply `return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());`. Look up Scopes in the eloquent docs - that seems like a much neater way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality you're looking for can be achieved using Authority (this package is based off of the rails CanCan gem by Ryan Bates): https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4.

First, you'll need to define your authority rules (see the examples in the docs) and then you can add filters to specific routes that have an id in them (edit, show, destroy) and inside the filter you can check your authority permissions to determine if the current user should be able to access the resource in question.